# Can I tell if a file is opened by a local macro--or, can I find who an instanced file's caller or parent is?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run a particular piece of code if and only if the target file is closed OR was opened by a local VBA macro. If the file is opened by a different user on the network, the code should not run.

So far I have this test code:

```
Sub refreshAll()
    Dim wbIsOpen As Boolean, wbIsOpenByMe As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String, filePath As String
    Dim testWb As Workbook

    fileName = "test.xlsm"

    If IsWorkBookOpen(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName) Then wbIsOpen = True

    On Error Resume Next
    Set testWb = Workbooks(fileName)
    If Not testWb Is Nothing Then wbIsOpenByMe = True
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wbIsOpen = False Or wbIsOpenByMe = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Connections("testcon").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        ThisWorkbook.refreshAll
        DoEvents
    End If
End Sub
```

This workaround kind-of-sort-of works, with the exception that it can't tell whether the file was opened manually or by some programmatic agent. Is there a way to do that, or is there an easier way to do what I've tried to do in my code?

Comment: Thre is no way of telling whether a workbook open in the current instance was opened by a user or by code, unless the code sets a flag of some sort. Why does it make a difference as a matter of interest?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` needs to perform some calculations and refresh some data connections only under certain conditions (when being called by the "central" file). If there is no way of reading whether the file was opened by vba or not, I have to add some lengthy redundancy. The necessity stems out of the connection-refresh: if the source of the data connection is not available upon the refresh-attempt, Excel tries to open a local copy of the file, which interrupts the flow of the macro. So I have to write a routine to catch this situation and open the file in the background to avoid code halt.

Comment: cont. I'm wary of having the calling file make calls to any macros that are local to the workbook being opened, because I have had timing issues before (macros being called before the workbook is open), so I resorted to putting the macro initialization in `Workbook_Open` of the file in question. And hence, the desire to know who/what opened the file.

Comment: I'm confused. Why does it matter whether the data source workbook was opened by a user or by code? If it's open, it's open.

Comment: The files are all available on a network share and may be opened by any number of users. If the file is being opened by code, I am guaranteed that the two files will be local to each other, and no code halt is encountered. But if one person has file A open, and another opens file B, file A will be busy and not local to file B, resulting in file B wanting to open a local copy of file A. This produces the code halt that I have to work around.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. That's totally different. Simply checking the `Workbooks` collection will tell you if the file is opened locally or not - it doesn't matter how it was opened. I assumed your `IsWorkbookOpen` function was taking care of the other part properly since you didn't post it.

Comment: `IsWorkBookOpen` is the one posted by Siddharth in some question about how to check if a workbook is available or not. It has worked without fail for me. And checking the `Workbooks` collection is what I've been doing - I swear I had a good reason for why I wanted to explore other options, but it escapes me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the macro which could be opening the file, do you have authority over it? Perhaps just have that macro change some protected value in the workbook - ie: have it add that moment's date and time to a hidden shape's title. Then this macro could check to see if the date and time on the title matches the current date and time (within a processing time margin of error).

This could work something like:

```
Sub MacroWhichCouldHaveBeenUsedToOpenWorkbook()

    'Other code
    'Code to open target workbook

    Workbooks("TargetWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Title = Now()

End Sub

Sub RunIfAutoOpened()

    If (Now + #0:00:05#) < Workbooks("TargetWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1).Shapes(1).Title Then
        'Run desired code
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using `Workbook_Open` to start the macro, so I don't think the caller will manage to write to the cell before the other macro has already run. But I will keep this in mind, might be able to hack something together. I can't test it until monday, but thanks for the input so far.

Comment: How about - in the macro which may or may not have opened the workbook, first change the property of a shape in the *old* workbook, and then run the workbook open command. And then under your Workbook_Open event, check whether (a) that previous workbook is open, and (b) the timer in that workbook on the shape there indicates that the workbook open macro was run.

Comment: That's a much smarter way to look at it... I'm a bit bummed I didn't think of that. I will check back when I've had a chance to try it out!